# confusion with frisch lovell type situation

Tags: regression, least-squares

Suppose I am trying to run a regression as follows:

$y= a_1+ b_1*x_1 +b_2*x_2 + e_1$

To study the relation between $y$ and $x_2$ net of their correlation with $x_1$, I run the following model first:

$y= a_2+ c_1*x_1 +e_2$

and fit the residuals obtained from this to $x_2$:

$\hat {e_2} = a_3+ d_2*x_2 +e_3$

What is the relation between $d_2$ and $b_2$?

I thought of Frisch-Waugh-Lovell Theorem, but that deals with regressing (residuals of $y$ on $x_1$) with (residuals on $x_2$ on $x_1$), and not on $x_2$ directly.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: actually i didnt have any data for it but saw it somewhere.